# How to prove this about standard deviation?

Tags: probability-theory

Let μ be the average of the random variable x. Then the quantities (xi −μ) are the
deviations of x from its average. Show that the average of these deviations is zero.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Generally in the SE sites it is a good practice to clearly formulate your question and then show what you have tried yourself. People like to help, but you should try to do it yourself first and then show at which point you got stuck at.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mu=\mu-\mu=0$

Comment: One of these equalities is a limit.

Comment: The original question did not specify how many $x_i$ there were - probably a factor in the nannies putting it on hold.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed two way (at least) to understand the notation then. I think you have the right one though.